# dom-to-image: Capture desktop components on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, render

I want to generate a PDF with images taken with `dom-to-image`.

On desktop, the generated PDF looks perfect, but if I switch to a mobile device the components are completely out of place.

The question is: Can I tell `dom-to-image` on mobile devices that it should render the components as they look on desktop?

Comment: I checked docs for dom-to-image. there's a height, width option in rendering options. Have you tried that? https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#height-width

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the alignment of the components itself, but there are also texts and images in the components and those aren't affected by the change of the width and the height. I saw there is the style option as well. Maybe I could set the existing css again before rendering. Do you know if this would work and how?